# Apacs 40 message authorization code

Tags: java, c#

Anyone got any knowledge or have implemented the apacs 40 message authorization code, I have manage to implement most of it where by I can verify the request Mac but I am not able to create a Mac for the response message ( I think that my problem is the authorization parameter or the pin key. Information on the subject is pretty much none existent on google and the apacs specs are the worse specs I have ever had the unpleasure to work out, so I would much appreciate any help from my fellow developer.

Comment: Add a code example which doesn't work for you would be good step.

Comment: Thanks, Will do tomorrow when I am at work.